# Stuck on Sticky header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to work out how this is done for a few hours and am no nearer than when I started.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-top-bar"></div>
    <div class="scrolling-bottom-bar"></div>
</div>
```

There's 3 bits to what I'm trying to do.

The `fixed-top-bar` is always `fixed` (easy of course)

The `scrolling-bottom-bar` initially sits beneath the `fixed-top-bar` (again easy by just adding an offset such as a top margin).

However, here's the bit I'm stuck with. The `container` (or the lowest part of the design) has a shadow at the bottom to indicate it is elevated. Initially this shadow sits below the `scrolling-lower-bar`, but as this disappears out of view, the shadow remains glued to the fixed-top-bar.

I'm unsure whether this can be done with `html/css` or it needs a bit of js. Here an example to illustrate that illustrated what I've been trying to replicate.

[example](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: still unclear to me, i didn't get what you want from the example

Comment: add your styles with this.

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş - you will see that the header has a shadow at the bottom - when the page scrolls the shadow moves up until the lower section disappears out of view - but the shadow still remains fixed to the yop bar.

Comment: Can you put this on jsFiddle?

Comment: ah, yeah, now its clear - may be you should try to make two different shadows one must be under the second non-fixed bar, and when the bars hide under the fixed, the second shadow will be visible ;) 3 different overlays with z-indeces, and i think javascript for this kinda stuff is too unnessecary ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use javascript
something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {     
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 0) {// you can add the height of your header
        $(".fixd-top").addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $(".fixd-top").removeClass("active");
    }
});




  CSS

    .fixed-top.active {
         box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code with inspector (f12) you will see when you scroll down, the css change in some element. This change must be done some javascript code, witch indicated when the user is scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

try the [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) property to check the vertical scrolling, the same property is in jquery.

or you can use an already written library like the [`Bootstrap Affix`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) or [`ScrollToFixed`](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed)